# lein help yields java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Running `lein noir new new-app` and `lein help` causes this long stack trace with many errors. I tried `lien self-install` after `rm -rf ~/.m2` though I still get these.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at jline.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:1578)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:399)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at leiningen.core$resolve_task.invoke(core.clj:208)
    at leiningen.core$apply_task.invoke(core.clj:258)
    at leiningen.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:329)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    at leiningen.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:332)
    at user$eval42.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:47)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:450)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
    at clojure.core$mapcat.doInvoke(core.clj:2122)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
    at leiningen.util.ns$namespaces_matching.invoke(ns.clj:68)
    at leiningen.help__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at leiningen.help__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor(Reflector.java:160)
    at leiningen.util.ns$namespaces_in_jar.invoke(ns.clj:52)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__3699.invoke(core.clj:2096)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My standard Leiningen fixing process is approximately:

- check your internet connection
- delete ~/.m2/repository/*
- delete /home/project/path/lib/*
- lein upgrade
- lein deps

this case looks like one of lein's required files is missing, though it can
be difficult to diagnose these problems. if you login to #clojure on irc.freenode.net
they are often helpful in figuring out these sorts of problem more interactively

Comment: Oops #clojure was able to help out. Needed to nuke lein and reinstall. Not sexy but it worked.

Comment: i'll add that to the list ;-) forgot about that old standby